# Android Reading from txt to hashmap

Tags: android, hashmap, readfile

I'm trying to make an app that reads from .txt file into a hashmap then prints a random hashmap entry on button click. But i am getting error like "FATAL EXCEPTION:main", i can figure out what the problem is.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    register r = new register();
    final HashMap<String, quote> quotes = r.getMap();


    final Random rand = new Random();

    final Button newQuote = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final Button clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Text1);
    newQuote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int i = rand.nextInt(4);
            String kode = ""+i;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            text.setText(quotes.get(kode).sitat);

        }
    });

    clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            text.setText("Sitat");
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });


}  

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}

class quote{
String kode;
String sitat;
String forfatter;

quote(String kode, String sitat, String forfatter){
    this.kode = kode;
    this.sitat = sitat;
    this.forfatter = forfatter;

}

public String hentSitat(){
    return sitat;

}
public String hentForfatter(){
    return forfatter;
}

}

class register{
HashMap<String, quote> quotes = new HashMap<String, quote>();

register(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner("sitater");

    while(sc.hasNext()){
        String linje = sc.nextLine();
        String[] split = linje.split("\t");
        String kode = split[0];
        String sitat = split[1];
        String forfatter = split[2];
        quote q = new quote(kode, sitat, forfatter);
        quotes.put(kode, q);
    }

}
HashMap<String, quote> getMap(){
    return quotes;
}
}
```

LogCat:

05-15 16:25:12.906: D/AndroidRuntime(4135): Shutting down VM
05-15 16:25:12.906: W/dalvikvm(4135): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.MorHam.qoutes/com.MorHam.qoutes.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135):     at com.MorHam.qoutes.register.(MainActivity.java:120)
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135):     at com.MorHam.qoutes.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135):     ... 11 more
05-15 16:25:12.998: D/dalvikvm(4135): GC_CONCURRENT freed 151K, 10% free 2698K/2972K, paused 15ms+36ms, total 166ms

Comment: me neither. Post your logcat

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the LogCat you've added:

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1 05-15 16:25:12.927: E/AndroidRuntime(4135): at com.MorHam.qoutes.register.(MainActivity.java:120)

That means that your array has **1** element and you are trying to access the second element.

```
String sitat = split[1];
```